# Como crear instalador con código ofuscado

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Tengo un programita hecho en `Visual Studio` y `C#`. Ofusque mi código probando con *ConfuserEx* y con *Obfuscar* pero con ninguno logro que al crear el instalador con `Visual Studio Installer` se quede ofuscado. Intente agregándolo como archivo con todas las dependencias cuando ofusque el codigo con *Confuser* (librerías y capa datos.dll y negocio.dll) y al momento de abrir la aplicación ingresé datos a la base de datos y todo bien pero al momento de visualizarlos en un `ReportViewer` y en un `DataGridWiev` no se visualizaban, salían las filas pero sin datos, y cuando abrí el programa sin código ofuscado si los podía ver. La pregunta es, ¿Cómo puedo crear el instalador con el archivo ofuscado?

Comment: aunque ya pasó un tiempo, te explico una manera por si te sirve a vos o a alguien más.
Yo utilizo un creador de instalador. Hay varios, inno setup es el que utilizo yo por ser simple y gratuito. Te permite seleccionar el archivo ejecutable y luego el resto de los archivos, ideal para este caso.
En ese proceso seleccionas el archivo que generaste con Obfuscar.
Espero que te sirva, saludos.